# Parse and iterate JSON with multiple headers

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm able to iterate through a simple json loop, but actually the API i'm working with returns a response with multiple headers and I tried different methods to access the `results` objects but still not working, the response looks like this:

> ```
> "meta": {
>     "name": "openaq-api",
>     "license": "CC BY 4.0",
>     "website": "https://docs.openaq.org/",
>     "page": 1,
>     "limit": 100,
>     "found": 1544
> },
> "results": [
>     {
>         "city": "Buenos Aires",
>         "country": "AR",
>         "locations": 4,
>         "count": 8064
>     },
>     {
>         "city": "Gemeinde Wien, MA22 Umweltschutz",
>         "country": "AT",
>         "locations": 21,
>         "count": 136958
>     },
> ```

What I'm trying to do is to access results then iterate with cities infos, my runnable attempts:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head><meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Open AQ API</title></head>

<body>

<div id="data"></div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

  var url = "https://api.openaq.org/v1/cities";

    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {

    var json = data

      $.each($.parseJSON(json), function() {
        alert(results.this.city);
      });

    });


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Attempt 2 :

```
// data[i]

$.each(data, function(i, item){
    $('#data').append(
        $('<h1>').text(item.results.city),
        $('<div>').text(item.results.country),
        $('<h6>').text(data[i].results.count),
);

});
```

Comment: That response is not valid JSON.

Comment: @SvenTheSurfer Why? Looks like real JSON

Comment: I realize the actual response is JSON, but the portion that you quoted is not.  You need to have the opening/closing brackets and close the array. `{"meta":{},"results":[{},{}]}` This is a pretty trivial problem, and I would recommend, instead of using built in functions like `$.each`, try it the old fashioned way with a `for` loop.  You will get a better understanding of how to access properties of objects.

Comment: @SvenTheSurfer Well - I'm looking to learn something different than for loops. I came from Python..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works just fine, try this instead for your jQuery.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head><meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Open AQ API</title></head>

<body>

<div id="data"></div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

  var url = "https://api.openaq.org/v1/cities";

    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {

      $.each(data.results, function(i, result) {
        console.log(result.city);
      });

    });


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly update below logic, data will give full response, SO you have to take results from data like $.parseJSON(json).results and then run for each loop as shown below.

```
 $.each(json.results, function(index,value) {// json is same as data as per your code
            alert(value.city);
          });
```